Trying to dynamically render a background of stars in Vue with Rive Animations
I am currently attempting to create a background for my website I am building using Vue. I have created small star animations in Rive and turned those animations into Vue Components. I am trying to now dynamically render these stars in the background of my website to make a nice space background. However, with my current implementation, it only draws one of the stars and puts it in the top left of the page instead of randomizing the position. The method to draw the static stars in a canvas works, but generating the dynamic stars made from Vue components is where the issue lies.
My current implementation attempts to create a container that takes up the full height and width of the current page, then it creates a list of star components with randomized locations, and finally, it attempts to loop through those star lists and render them in the background. Here is the page where all of this is happening:
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <!-- Canvas Background -->
    <canvas ref="spaceCanvas" class="background-canvas"></canvas>

    <!-- Rive Stars Containers -->
    <div class="stars-container">
      <div class="normal-stars">
        <NormalStar v-for="star in normalStars" :key="star.id" :style="{ top: star.y + 'px', left: star.x + 'px' }" />
      </div>
      <div class="purple-stars">
        <PurpleStar v-for="star in purpleStars" :key="star.id" :style="{ top: star.y + 'px', left: star.x + 'px' }" />
      </div>
      <div class="orange-stars">
        <OrangeStar v-for="star in orangeStars" :key="star.id" :style="{ top: star.y + 'px', left: star.x + 'px' }" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Overlaying Content -->
    <div class="content-overlay">
      <main>
        <!-- This router view shows the main pages (Created in router/index.js) -->
        <router-view />
      </main>
      <footer>
        <!-- Vertical Spacing -->
        <div class="vertical-spacing"></div>
        <div class="vertical-spacing"></div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="container d-flex flex-column gap-4 col-6 align-items-center">
          <div class="d-flex gap-4">
            <LinkedIn />
            <Github />
            <Indeed />
            <Instagram />
          </div>
          <p>Created by <b>Justice Gooch</b></p>
          <Earth />
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

// Icons
import Github from "./components/icons/github.vue";
import LinkedIn from "./components/icons/linkedin.vue";
import Indeed from "./components/icons/indeed.vue";
import Instagram from "./components/icons/instagram.vue";

// Illustrations
import Earth from "./components/static-illustrations/Earth.vue";
import PurpleStar from "./components/rive-illustrations/PurpleStar.vue";
import NormalStar from "./components/rive-illustrations/NormalStar.vue";
import OrangeStar from "./components/rive-illustrations/OrangeStar.vue";

// Refs for normal, purple, and orange stars
const normalStars = ref([]);
const purpleStars = ref([]);
const orangeStars = ref([]);

const spaceCanvas = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  const canvas = spaceCanvas.value;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Set canvas width and height to match the content height
  canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight;

  // Handle window resize
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    // Set canvas width and height to match the content height
    canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    // Redraw stars on resize
    drawStars();
    generateStars();
  });

  // Function to draw background stars
  function drawStars() {
    const numberOfStars = 100;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
      const x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
      const y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
      const radius = Math.random() * 1.5;
      const alpha = Math.random();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${alpha})`;
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }

  // Function to generate star positions for each category
  function generateStars() {
    function generateStarCoordinates(count) {
      const starsArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        starsArray.push({
          id: i,
          x: Math.random() * document.body.scrollWidth,
          y: Math.random() * document.body.scrollHeight,
        });
      }
      return starsArray;
    }

    debugger;
    // Populate the stars arrays
    normalStars.value = generateStarCoordinates(150);
    purpleStars.value = generateStarCoordinates(10);
    orangeStars.value = generateStarCoordinates(10);
  }

  // Initial drawing of stars and generation of Rive stars
  drawStars();
  generateStars();
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.page-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.stars-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  pointer-events: none;
}

.normal-stars,
.purple-stars,
.orange-stars {
  position: absolute;
}

.content-overlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
</style>

And for example, here is one of my star components (that appear to work correctly by themselves):
<template>
  <canvas id="riveNormalStar" class="star-canvas" width="18" height="18"></canvas>
</template>

<script setup>

import * as rive from "@rive-app/canvas";
import {onMounted} from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const r = new rive.Rive({
    src: 'src/assets/rive/portfolio.riv',
    canvas: document.getElementById("riveNormalStar"),
    autoplay: true,
    artboard: "Normal Star",
    animations: ["Timeline 1"],
    onLoad: () => {
      r.resizeDrawingSurfaceToCanvas();
    },
  });
})

</script>

<style scoped>
  .star-canvas {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
  }
</style>

Based on testing, and the fact that at least one of the stars appears, I believe the issue has to be an issue with the logic I am using to generate the list of stars and show them using the v-for loop. Does anyone see anything that could be causing this?
UPDATE
I figured out the issue was because my stars were not being given unique identifiers. Once I gave them unique ID's and fixed some small CSS issues it works great :)

@Yogi There are no errors in the console!

is it the stars drawn by drawStars or generateStars you have an issue with? I'd check (browser developer tools) the dimensions of the canvas for the former, or <div class="stars-container"> for the latter

@JaromandaX I actually figured it out, thanks though for your help!
